# Plot Log scale on X-Axis?

Tags: plotting

There's documentation on how to do a [LogPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogPlot.html) with respect to Y-axis, but how would you do the same for the X-axis? Is there some Plot option?

For example, here are some examples that plot Log scale on x-axis. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise

Comment: Is `LogLinearPlot` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is pretty clear in the documentation. See: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogLinearPlot.html.

Use `LogLinearPlot` or `ListLogLinearPlot` for just the x-axis or `LogLogPlot` or `ListLogLogPlot` for both axes.

Comment: Hello @kale, the ListLogLinearPlot can be used only with discete data, instead LogLinearPlot with continuous data?